# Release UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift

I've written a game in Swift where I'm running into memory problems.
This is because I create a new UIViewController for every new level.
I would like to release this UIViewController.
I stumbled across the following solution on Stackoverflow:

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
[gvc release];
```

Can anyone help me getting the Swift equivalent. I have

```
let gvc = (name: storyboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(gvcStoryboardIdentifier) as GameViewController
gvc. ... //setting a few properties


presentViewController(gvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

//how do I release the current controller that is presenting the new ViewController?
```

EDIT: Here's the code

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, NavigationDelegate   
{
      var currentLevel = 0
var remainingLives = totalAmountOfLives
weak var scene : GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as GameScene


    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    //skView.showsFPS = true
    //skView.showsNodeCount = true

    scene.navigationDelegate = self
    scene.level = currentLevel
    scene.remainingLives = remainingLives
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)  

}

      func showWinner(time: NSTimeInterval)
        {

        scene.removeFromParent() //trying to release some space
        scene = nil
        ScoreSaver.addToScore(time) //add the time needed to complete this level

        if(currentLevel + 1 == amountLevels) //all levels have been completed
        {
            weak var wonAllLevelsController = (UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(wonAllLevelsIdentifier) as WonAllLevelsViewController)


            presentViewController(wonAllLevelsController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.removeFromParentViewController() //save memory

        }
        else
        {
            weak var wonGameController = (UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(wonGameControllerIdentifier) as WonGameController)
            wonGameController!.elapsedTime = time
            wonGameController!.level = currentLevel
            wonGameController!.remainingLives = remainingLives



            presentViewController(wonGameController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
```

In the WonGameViewController I have a button that guides the user to the next level.

```
class WonGameViewController{

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == nextLevelSegueIdentifier {




            weak var gameViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as GameViewController)
            gameViewController!.currentLevel = ++level % amountLevels //advance to the next level
            gameViewController!.remainingLives = remainingLives
            self.removeFromParentViewController()



    }

}
}
```

Within the SKScene CPU intensive operations are performed. Whenever I advance to the next level the consumed memory increases by about 2MB. Sometimes (I don't know when), it suddenly increases by 40MB

Comment: Swift does not encourage manual memory management - I would recommend reading up on automatic reference counting (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_88), and how you can use it in place of manual retain/release cycles. (Which have been all but deprecated in Swift. You can cast to `Unmanaged` types, but in your scenario, it's not necessary.)

Comment: Please show the code that creates you memory problems as it seems the code you have posted will not solve your problem.

Comment: Your problem, I suspect, is that you never pop the **old** view controller off the navigation controller's stack.  If you do pop it, show us the code.

Comment: I might also suggest that since you're using SpriteKit, you should just use one view controller and replace the scene of your `SKView` instead of pushing new view controllers at all.

Comment: @Rob. I'm quite sure that it is the fact that I'm creating new ViewControllers over and over again. So I'm trying to pop it at the very end of the showWinner method by:
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false).
Still memory increases but that much than before.

Comment: If you're popping the old view controller, and you're not keeping a reference to it, then maybe that's not why your memory use is increasing.  You need to use the Allocations instrument to figure out where your memory is going.

Comment: I'm now exchanging the scenes. It seems that using storyboard for menus in combination with SpriteKit is not a good idea